# Autocomplete system with prefix tree

Tags: programming-challenge, haskell, trie

I am quite new to Haskell, and this problem is from dailycodingproblem.com:

> Implement an autocomplete system.
> That is, given a query string `s` and a set of all possible query strings,
> return all strings in the set that have `s` as a prefix.
> For example, given the query string `de` and the set of strings `[dog, deer, deal]`, return `[deer, deal]`.
>
> Hint: Try preprocessing the dictionary into a more efficient data structure to speed up queries.

```hs
import Data.Map.Strict (Map)
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import Data.HashSet (HashSet)
import qualified Data.HashSet as HashSet

data Trie = Trie {children :: Map Char Trie, wordsWithPrefix :: HashSet String} deriving Show

emptyTrie :: Trie
emptyTrie = Trie Map.empty HashSet.empty

insertWord :: Trie -> String -> Trie
insertWord trie [] = trie
insertWord (Trie childs wwp) (x:xs) = Trie newChildren newWordsWithPrefix
    where   
    childTrie = Map.findWithDefault emptyTrie x childs
    newChildTrie = insertWord childTrie xs
    newChildren = Map.insert x newChildTrie childs
    newWordsWithPrefix = HashSet.insert (x:xs) wwp

searchPrefix :: Trie -> String -> HashSet String
searchPrefix trie [] = wordsWithPrefix trie
searchPrefix trie (x:xs) =
    case Map.lookup x (children trie) of
        Nothing -> HashSet.empty
        Just child -> HashSet.map (x:) (searchPrefix child xs)

makeTrie :: [String] -> Trie
makeTrie wordSet = foldl insertWord emptyTrie wordSet

autocomplete :: [String] -> String -> [String]
autocomplete wordSet s = HashSet.toList $ searchPrefix (makeTrie wordSet) s
```

It works, but I'm not sure about the performance and less sure that it aligns with best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first instinct here was to not respond, on the basis that there's not much to add. I'm not about to set up benchmarking to measure the performance, and the code is fine idiomatic haskell. Specifically, there's just small set of functions that do obvious things and combine in obvious ways. What's not to like?

Except...

The nature of a Trie is that the data is encoded in the data-structure's *structure*. So why are you storing it in duplicate in the `wordsWithPrefix` field? Our instinct is to store things in just one way; whether it's more efficient or not, it avoids *conflicts* between the different storage systems.

Of course it's not obvious else we should be doing it, and there may be performance advantages to your strategy. Do we want a separate `Leaf String` constructor for when there's only one suffix going forward from a node? How do we distinguish the Tries of `["abc"]` and `["ab", "abc"]`? Of course we could (and really, we probably *should*) just use something from [the `tries` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tries), but if we're going to roll our own we should first try to have as few moving parts as possible. I came up with

```hs
data Trie = Occupied (Map Char Trie) | UnOccupied (Map Char Trie)
```

Take a moment to notice a semantic detail implicit in this declaration: `emptyTrie` is obviously `UnOccupied Map.empty`, which is different from `Occupied Map.empty`; therefore `insertWord trie []` *is not* `trie`!

Of course having written that, I immediately abstracted out the `Char` in favor of `data Trie a = ...`, and after working with it for a minute I switched to the less-pretty but more-user-friendly

```hs
data Trie a = Trie { children :: Map Char (Trie a), occupied :: Bool }
```

`insertWord` is doing most of your work, so let's focus on that for a moment. Using `{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}` and record syntax, I get

```hs
insertWord :: Trie a -> [a] -> Trie a
insertWord trie [] = trie{occupied=True}
insertWord trie@Trie{children} (x:xs) = trie{children=newChildren}
  where childTrie = Map.findWithDefault emptyTrie x children
        newChildTrie = insertWord childTrie xs
        newChildren = Map.insert x newChildTrie children
```

What else do I find as I go?

- `searchPrefix` should probably return a List; the conversion will need to happen someplace and doing it here makes some stuff simpler.
- Using `mempty` instead of the various things it can stand for saves the need to changes stuff as your implementation changes, and is often more succinct.
- Many data structures have a `singleton` option to go with `empty`; might as well give `Trie` one too.
- Many data structures have a `toList` and `fromList`; you can use all of these interchangeably with `import GHC.Exts (fromList, toList)`. Might as well implement `IsList (Trie a)` instead of `makeTrie`.
- The presence of `emptyTrie` is suggestive of the `Monoid` class. Implement `Semigroup` and `Monoid` for `Trie`.
- The payoff of implementing all this stuff for `Trie` is, in addition to making your data type more generally useful, that you can now implement `insertWord` and `searchPrefix` succinctly in terms of class operations.
- Rename `emptyTrie` and `insertWord` to `empty` and `insert` for consistency with `Map` and other comparable data structures.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module Main where
import Data.List (sort)
import Data.Map.Strict (Map)
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import GHC.Exts (IsList(Item), fromList, toList)

data Trie a = Trie { children :: Map a (Trie a), occupied :: Bool } deriving Show

empty :: Trie a  -- We could skip this in favor of mempty, but `Map` has it's own empty which doesn't require `Ord`, so we'll follow their lead.
empty = Trie Map.empty False

singleton :: [a] -> Trie a
singleton [] = empty{occupied=True}
singleton (a:as) = empty{children = Map.singleton a $ singleton as}

instance (Ord a) => Semigroup (Trie a) where
  t1 <> t2 = Trie {children = Map.unionWith (<>) (children t1) (children t2), occupied = occupied t1 || occupied t2}
instance (Ord a) => Monoid (Trie a) where mempty = empty

instance (Ord a) => IsList (Trie a) where
  type Item (Trie a) = [a]
  fromList = foldMap singleton
  toList Trie{children, occupied} = [ [] | occupied]  -- this syntax isn't well documented, but works fine and is kinda common.
                                    ++ (concatMap accumulate . toList . fmap toList $ children)
    where accumulate (a, as) = (a:) <$> as  -- Pretty sure we could replace this with some trainwreak based on `curry (:)`, but let's not.

insert :: (Ord a) => Trie a -> [a] -> Trie a
insert trie as = trie <> singleton as

search :: (Ord a) => Trie a -> [a] -> [[a]]
search trie [] = toList trie
search Trie{children} (x:xs) =
  case Map.lookup x children of
    Nothing -> mempty
    Just child -> (x:) <$> search child xs

autocomplete :: [String] -> String -> [String]
autocomplete wordSet = search (fromList wordSet)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let ws = ["dog", "deer", "deal"]
    let res = autocomplete ws "de"
    print res
    print $ sort res == sort ["deer", "deal"]
```